# Python update self.__dict__ in __getattribute__ immediately

Tags: python, object

I am doing nested object and I am able to perform dot tab auto-complete to navigate to the next level of the object. I understand that `__getattribute__` is called and if the name is not found in the `self.__dict__` then `__getattr__` will be called. Correct me if I am wrong.

Is it possible to update `self.__dict__` in overwriting `__getattribute__`, and when I perform the dot tab it shows the updated option to auto-complete?

My current implementation:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if condition:
        object.__setattr__(self, '__dict__', dictionary to be added)
    else:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

I am able to add the object but it's not available in the first tab, it is only available in the second tab.

What I am trying to achieve is for the tab to show the updated object/variable on the first tab. I am thinking about `return` something instead of just `__setattr__`, But I have no idea what to return. Any pointer will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting the `__dir__`, as it is called in the pyreadline.